# PHP ZipArchive doesn't create a zip archive. What to fix in the code?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have an .srt file located in the files/srt/username/filename.srt directory. I need to be able to download it in the browser, but to make this possible I have to zip the file first.
I found the following code online:

```
function download_zip() {
    if (isset($_POST['download_srt'])) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open("files/srt/".$_SESSION['user_name']."/".$_POST['download_srt'].".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
        // output: files/srt/username/filename.srt.zip

        $zip->addFile($_POST['download_srt']);
        // output of $_POST['download_srt']: filename.srt

        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

The code is called when a submit button is pressed and the $_POST data are sent.
The function works, but no ZIP file gets created in the same directory as the original srt file. No error messages appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the correct path to the file to add:

```
$zip->addFile("files/srt/".$_SESSION['user_name']."/".$_POST['download_srt']);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! Also if you want the file not to be zipped with its directory, you should provide a second parameter to this function. The first one is the directory of the file, the second one is the name of the file you want to zip. If you provide a path in a second parameter, the file will be zipped with the provided path.